# How to simulate random point following multivariate t distribution?

Tags: matlab, probability, distribution

If `X` is a multivariate t random variable with `mean=[1,2,3,4,5]` and a covariance matrix `C`, how to simulate points in matlab? I try mvtrnd in matlab, but clearly the sample mean does not give mean close to `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Also, when I test three simple examples, say `X1` with mean 0 and `C1=[1,0.3;0.3,1]`, `X2` with mean 0 and `C2=[0.5,0.15;0.15,0.5]` and `X3` with mean 0 and `C3=[0.4,0.12;0.12,0.4]` and use `mvtrnd(C1,3,1000000)`, `mvtrnd(C2,3,1000000)` amd `mvtrnd(C2,3,1000000)` respectively, I find the sample points in each case give nearly the correlation matrix `[1,0.3;0.3,1]` but the sample covariance computed all give near `[3,1;1,3]`. Why and how to fix it?

Comment: The [*t* distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) has a zero mean unless you shift it.  In the documentation for [`mvtrnd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvtrnd.html): "*the distribution of t is that of a vector having a multivariate normal distribution with mean 0, variance 1, and covariance matrix C, divided by an independent chi-square random value having df degrees of freedom.*" Indeed, `mean(X)` will approach `[0 0]` for `X = mvtrnd(C,df,n);` as `n` gets [larger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers).

Comment: Shifting is not a problem. Then how do I generate points using mvtrnd when C=[0.4,0.12;0.4,0.12]? When we simulate points using mvtrnd when C=[0.4,0.12;0.4,0.12] or C=[1,0.3;0.3,1], mvtrnd would automatically make C to be a correlation matrix, so [0.4,0.12;0.4,0.12] would change to [1,0.3;0.3,1] for input. How do I get back the points with covariance [0.4,0.12;0.4,0.12]?

Comment: C is covariance matrix. For example, if C1=[0.4,0.12;0.12,0.4] and C2=[0.5,0.15;0.15,0.5], both of them have correlation matrix [1,0.3;0.3,1], right? In the documentation, mvtrnd requires C to be correlation matrix, otherwise it will automatically transform to correlation matrix first, so mvtrnd([0.4,0.12;0.12,0.4],...) and mvtrnd([0.5,0.15;0.15,0.5],...) should be no difference. However, if X is student t with covariance [0.4,0.12;0.12,0.4] and Y is student with covariance [0.5,0.15;0.15,0.5], X,Y should be different and can be reflected from the simulated point, but not through experiment.

Comment: Yes, I'm running into something similar. I was confirming with [`corrcov`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/corrcov.html).  I'll need to think about this.

Comment: @will_cheuk kindly use the code format  when editing your post to make it readable

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Seldom use the platform.

Answer (score 2):

**The Mean**
The [*t* distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) has a zero mean unless you shift it. In the documentation for [mvtrnd](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvtrnd.html):

> the distribution of t is that of a vector having a multivariate normal
>   distribution with mean 0, variance 1, and covariance matrix C, divided
>   by an independent chi-square random value having df degrees of
>   freedom.

Indeed, `mean(X)` will approach `[0 0]` for `X = mvtrnd(C,df,n);` as `n` gets [larger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers).

**The Correlation**
Matching the correlation is straightforward as it addresses a part of the relationship between the two dimensions of `X`.

```
% MATLAB 2018b
df = 5;                        % degrees of freedom
C = [0.44 0.25; 0.25 0.44];    % covariance matrix
numSamples = 1000;

R = corrcov(C);                % Convert covariance to correlation matrix
X = mvtrnd(R,df,numSamples);   % X ~ multivariate t distribution
```

You can compare how well you matched the correlation matrix `R` using [`corrcoef`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html) or `corr()`.

```
corrcoef(X)               % Alternatively, use corr(X)
```

**The Covariance**
Matching the covariance is another matter. Admittedly, calling `cov(X)` will reveal that this is lacking. Recall that the diagonal of the covariance is the variance for the two components of `X`. My intuition is that we fixed the degrees of freedom `df`, so there is no way to match the desired variance (& covariance).

---

A useful function is [`corrcov`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/corrcov.html) which  converts a [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) into a [correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) matrix.

Notice that this is unnecessary as the documentation for [`mvtrnd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvtrnd.html) indicates

> C must be a square, symmetric and positive definite matrix. If its
>   diagonal elements are not all 1 (that is, if C is a covariance matrix
>   rather than a correlation matrix), mvtrnd rescales C to transform it
>   to a correlation matrix before generating the random numbers.

Comment: Still not solve the problem. If X is multivariate t with C1=[0.4,0.12;0.4,0.12] and Y is multivariate t with C2=[0.5,0.15;0.15,0.5]. The two random variables are different so the simulated point should be different. One set of simulated point should show sample covariance closed to C1 while another set of simulated point should show sample covariance closed to C2. But numerical experiment show that suggested method gives sample covariance different from C1 and C2. Then I cannot use the simulated points.

Comment: I understand your concern. I believe this is due to fixing the degrees of freedom.  I assess this is preventing the results from achieving the desired variance (& covariance). You can see this from the importance of the parameterization. I wish I could help further - someone else may have the missing piece.  Otherwise, there's always [CrossValidated SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).  If you find the answer, please post something here & ping me with "@myusername".  I'm interested.